# OctoberCMS | Db class for multi-argument query

Tags: octobercms

I'm trying to fire a simple multi-arg query using the static class **Db**, but I get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select idy, keywords  FROM jb_tal_detail WHERE tid = 1 AND idy= ?)
```

This is my query, where both variables exist:

```
Db::select('select  idy, keywords  FROM  jb_tal_detail WHERE tid = ? AND idy= ?', [$uid], [$idy] );
```

From the error msg looks like $idy is not defined ($idy=1), or the 2nd argument is not allowed (really?).

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
Db::select('select  idy, keywords  FROM  jb_tal_detail WHERE tid = ? AND idy= ?', [$uid, $idy] );
```

Comment: No problem, if it solved your problem you should accept the answer as it may help others.